# Can't access value in array using variable to specify index

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo '<br>' . 'id: ' . $id . '<br><br>';

echo '<pre>';
            print_r($itemQtys);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<br>' . 'itemqtys[id]: ' . $itemQtys[$id] . '<br>';

echo '<br>' . 'id: ' . $id . '<br>';
```

The output is:

> id: 5
>
> Array
>    (
>               [5] => 12
>     )
>
> itemqtys[id]:
>
> id: 5

As you can see, when I try to access the value in the array using the $id variable as the key, no value is returned. However, when I do this:

```
echo '<br>' . 'itemqtys[5]: ' . $itemQtys[5] . '<br>';
```

The result is:

> itemqtys[5]: 12

Why can't I use a variable to specify the index in the array?

Comment: where is `$id`? It's not set to anything in your example. How are you creating it?

Comment: I didn't think how it was being gotten was relevant, as I showed it's value. I've updated my question, however, and to answer your question: it is passed as a GET value.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ` at the start of your script (or read the error log) and you'll probably see a warning which will indicate that `$id` isn't exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when debugging use var_dump() to inspect values. Notice var dump tells you the string length. right click > view html source when debugging too.

My guess is that $id is a string and has trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: "My guess is that $id is a string and has trailing whitespace characters" sounds quite answery (and quite likely the error) to me.

Comment: I think my answer is pretty good actually- I both teach how to fish, and give a fish.

Comment: "I think my answer is pretty good actually- I both teach how to fish, and give a fish." LOL! Yes, you're answer was very good. Thank you! I checked if the id was a number via the function is_numeric(), but apparently in PHP something can still be a number even if it has a space in front of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$id` probably does not contain what you expect, cast it to an integer first.

Change your first line to:

`$id = (int) $_GET['id']`;

`$_GET['id']` returns a string and you have to cast it to `int` before using it as an array index.

Comment: php casts string to int (and vice versa) for array keys automatically. "and you have to cast it to int before passing it to you array." -- nope, they don't have to: http://ideone.com/7jdC5

Comment: @zerkms, I don't think you're entirely right. If you access an array like `$itemQtys['5']` it will get casted correctly. But if there's a space (and that is entirely possible in user input), it won't cast the value but rather treat it as string: `$itemQtys[' 5']`. So trimming or better yet casting the user input isn't a bad idea. -- http://ideone.com/vx2St

Comment: @zerkms You are correct, but it seems bad practice to me to use a string when you know you need an integer.

Comment: @Czechnology: right, **BUT** answerer didn't state this explicitly, and said that it is *required* to cast to integer, without explanation for what reason. Without such examples the answer itself looks incorrect. "So trimming or better yet casting the user input isn't a bad idea" --- it is a good idea, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: ilanco - thank you for the suggestion on typecasting the GET value. I think I am going to start doing this from now on to stop this problem from occurring again. Thanks.